# How to set 'nmixures' and 'bShadowDetection' values in 'BackgroundSubtractorMOG2'?

Tags: c++, image, opencv, image-processing, artificial-intelligence

Please have a look at the following code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/video/background_segm.hpp>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

Mat frame,back,fore;

int main()
{
    VideoCapture cam;
    BackgroundSubtractorMOG2 bgs(0,0,false);
    vector<vector<Point>>contours;

    bgs.setInt("nmixtures",3);

    cam.open(0);

    if(!cam.isOpened())
    {
        cout << "Cam not Found";
        return -1;
    }



    namedWindow("Frame");

    while(true)
    {
        cam>>frame;
        imshow("Frame",frame);

        if(waitKey(30)>=0)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to set the value of `nmixures` of `BackgroundSubtractorMOG2` into 3 and `bShadowDetection` of `BackgroundSubtractorMOG2`  into `false`.

However, as with OpenCV 2.4.5, these values are set to private, so I can't acess them directly. I managed to set the value of   `bShadowDetection` via the constructor (Eventhough I dnt know what other 2 params are), and I couldn't find a way to set the `nmixers`. I don't know whether The way I set the nmixures is correct or not,because in the article I read, the writer says "Set them via constructors in case of opencv 2.4"

Can you please tell me how to set those 2 values?

Comment: Try bgs.setNMixtures(int nmix)

Answer (score 2):

In OpenCV 2.4.8.:

```
bgs.set("nmixtures", 3);
bgs.set("detectShadows", false);
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case, you have to write:

```
BackgroundSubtractorMOG2 bgs;
bgs.setInt("nmixtures", 3);
bgs.setBool("detectShadows", false);
```